# Django - How to fill modelform field from database when field not in model?

Tags: django

How do I fill a non-model field in a modelform with a value from the database before validation?

```
if request.POST:
        formset = StudentScheduleFormSet(request.POST,)
        for form in formset: 
            if not form.initial.get('course_term'):
                form.initial['course_term'] = CourseTerm.objects.get(course=form.data['course'], term=form.data['term'])
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
```

I've tried this and about twenty other variations including modifying `__init__` on the form and I keep getting close but can't quite make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `data` instead of `initial`

You can try this:

```
if request.POST:
        formset = StudentScheduleFormSet(request.POST,)
        for form in formset: 
            if not form.data['course_term']:
                form_obj.course_term = CourseTerm.objects.get(course=form.cleaned_data['course'], term=form.cleaned_data['term'])
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
```

OR

```
if request.POST:
        formset = StudentScheduleFormSet(request.POST,)
        for form in formset: 
            if form.is_valid():
                if not form.cleaned_data.get('course_term'):
                    form_obj = form.save(commit=False)
                    form_obj.course_term = CourseTerm.objects.get(course=form.cleaned_data['course'], term=form.cleaned_data['term'])
                    form_obj.save()
                else:
                    form.save()
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
```

Comment: That's great. This is part of a formset though (I didn't mention that) and now it can't find the key since "form-#-" is prepended.

Comment: did you try it out ? Since you are doing form in formset, that should not be the case

Comment: I did try it and I am surprised that happened too.

Comment: Where did form_obj come from?

Comment: from the return of `form.save(commit=False)`

Comment: OH! I only tried the first example and that part isn't there.I tried the second one just now and I no longer get exceptions but the course_term still will not save.

Comment: glad it helped. Please Do accept the answer if you found it useful.